# Salesforce Reports: Condense multiselect values to one line

Tags: salesforce, report, concatenation, one-to-many, salesforce-lightning

I am working within a Salesforce report where I list the organization name in one column and the organizational types in the other. Some organizations only have one org type and as such would only have one record/line in the report. Other organizations have two or more organization types and appear multiple times in the report (one line for each org type). Is there a way within Reports in Lighting in cases where more than one org type exists to condense/concatenate them all in one cell so that the record only appears once?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Matrix report where rows would be grouped by org and column would be types (type names?). Cells on intersection would contain 0 or 1, looks bit weak but would get the job done.

Other than that you might be looking into some config (analytic snapshot?) or maybe even code to kind of rollup types by org into 1 helper field on org. And what would that be evem, test field? mutlipicklist? Doable, sometimes needed but bit messy. You'd need to rollup on insert, update, delete, undelete (restore from recycle bin, ideally you'd cover that scenario too even though there's no bin in lightning yet)

Comment: Thanks @eyescream. A matrix report isn't really what I'm looking for. I would want the names of all org types to be named in one column so that I could also include other columns such as the org address and organization contact in the same report. We could certainly write code to roll these up but I was hoping Salesforce would have some existing functionality to do so.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Probably even Analytic Snapshot won't save you. What are you thinking about, some comma-separated list? Maybe multipicklist. But yeah, sounds like data fix needed / code solution. And it's a pain because if you want to do it by the book you should react on delete too (so trigger, not workflow/process builder). Check if "declarative rollup" managed package doesn't have something for such "text rollup"